# Can't get my new masonry bit to go further than about 3/4"

Tags: framing, masonry

I bought a home last year and have been trying to put up interior walls inside my shop in the back yard.  I built a wood frame and want to secure the frames to the concrete floor using masonry screws.  The screws came with a masonry bit but I also bought an additional one just in case.  My first hole I drilled went about 1 1/2 inches and since then I am unable to drill further than 3/4" into the concrete in multiple spots using both bits.  For the life of me I cannot figure out why it can't go any further. I have tried vacuuming away debris while drilling, using oil in case the tip was getting too hot and just increasing speed and pressure in case I wasn't going fast enough.  I don't think I am any where deep enough to hit rebar either.

I am completely stumped.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a hammer drill?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I know having one would help greatly but I currently do not.

Comment: You're probably drilling into a rock in the concrete...  rent a hammer drill.

Comment: I had to fix some concrete furniture this year and don't have a hammer drill either and sure enough I hit some rock too. I didn't rent a hammer drill, instead I slowed down, and started to blow out the dust and drilled progressively larger pilot holes until I got back to the size I needed. Try that maybe???

Comment: Has no one thought about rebar? A good masonry bit and hammer drill Moyer can be stopped by metal! Wow. Even a non hammer drill would not be stopped at the same depth for multiple holes.

Comment: Flooding with water works much better to cool and remove debris. Hammer drill also work much better.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably hit a bit of hard stone aggregate in the masonry and you’re using a regular drill and not a hammer drill.

Masonry bits have hardened tips but on hard stone, the tip will just skip and slide if you’re using a regular drill.

A [hammer drill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_drill?wprov=sfti1) adds percussive hammering to the drill so that the hardened tip can break up any aggregate or stones in its way. Hammer drills have gotten quite cheap ($30-$50 for a chinesium corded one) so you should think of buying one.

[image: hf hammer drill]

A [rotary hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_hammer?wprov=sfti1) which a commenter suggested is a hammer drill on steroids. Bigger, heavier, stronger, and more expensive. Definitely overkill for your purposes but great to have if you’re drilling through hardened concrete, want to make larger or deeper holes, need the chiseling function and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Just use some liquid nails.  Get some PL premium and glue the bottom plate.

It doesn't sound like you want to invest in tools if you don't even have a hammer drill.  You could also use powder actuated fasteners.  PAF tools can be rented and use a small charge to get the nails embeded.

Or get a hammer drill and drill.

If you insist on making it as hard as possible on yourself you could use a standard hammer and one of your bits and simulate the action of the hammer drill by striking the bit manually rotating it and repeating.